# U-SQL - Execution related queries

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I wrote multiple U-SQL scripts and its output got stored in ADLA, based on this I have few question.

- How we can run dependent jobs in U-SQL?
- How to execute statement based on some condition like

> ```
> If RecordCount > 0 then
>      insert into table1
> endif
> ```

- How we can schedule U-SQL jobs?
- Can we write multiple scripts and call them from main script?
- During script execution, compiler prepare and compiles the code. It took almost 30-40 secs. How we can bundle the compiled code and create the ADF pipeline?

Comment: U-SQL does not support the concept of `UPDATE` and has limited control flow (eg `if ... then .... else`).  One option for scheduling jobs with Azure Data Factory.  You can encapsulate code in stored procedures, views and functions.

Comment: Updated my question... I know U-SQL doesn't support update, my question is based on some condition, I want to insert into a a particular table.

Comment: Just have two 'INSERT' statements where the 'WHERE' clause controls what goes into the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can schedule and orchestrate U-SQL jobs with Azure Data Factory or by writing your own scheduler with one of the SDKs (Powershell, C#, Java, node.js, Python).

U-SQL supports two ways for conditional execution:

1. If your conditional can be evaluated at compile time, e.g., when you pass a parameter value or [check for the existence of a file](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2016/2016_09_12/USQL_Release_Notes_2016_09_12.md#new-scalar-file-and-partition-object-functions-are-available-to-test-for-presence-and-other-properties), you can use the [`IF` statement](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2016/2016_08_01/USQL_Release_Notes_2016_08_01.md#u-sql-supports-a-compile-time-if-statement).
2. If your conditional can only be determined during the execution of the script, then you can use the `WHERE` clause as wBob outlines in his comment.

As wBob mentions, you can encapsulate most of the U-SQL statements in procedures and then call them from other scripts/procedures, or you can write your own way of inclusion/orchestration if you need script file reuse.

There is currently no ability to reuse and submit just compiled code, since the compilation depends on the exact information such as what files are present and the statistics of the accessed data.

Comment: Can I use wildcard with FILE.EXISTS("/raw_files/abc*.txt)? Does it work?

Comment: At this point it does not support wildcards. Feel free to file a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.